# Use PHP to replace database string

Tags: php, database, string, replace

Here is my code:

```
            echo "<td>" . $row4['CMUSERID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row4['CMCLAS'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row4['CMRACE'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row4['CMGEND'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row4['CMSTRE'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row4['CMDEXT'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row4['CMCONS'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row4['CMWISD'] . "</td>";
```

Here is a link to the page that shows the results:

http://oge.sytes.net/zetzer/includes/characters.php

How do I modify my php code to eliminate the PlayerClass and PlayerRace from the display, so if they haven't chosen a class or race, it shows up empty? I cannot change it in the database, so it has to be replaced in the php display

Comment: Check if the value for that field in the row is empty or not, and `continue;` if it is?

Comment: `$row4['CMCLAS'] == "PlayerClass" ? "" : $row4['CMCLAS']`

Comment: you just need to change yours query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        echo "<td>" . $row4['CMUSERID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
             echo $row4['CMCLAS'] == "PlayerClass" ? "&nbsp;" : $row4['CMCLAS'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
             echo $row4['CMRACE'] == "PlayerRace" ? "&nbsp;" : $row4['CMRACE'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row4['CMGEND'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row4['CMSTRE'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row4['CMDEXT'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row4['CMCONS'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row4['CMWISD'] . "</td>";
```

You may want to replace "`&nbsp;`" whatever you like.